# Proper way for a client desktop application to query SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection

Say I have an application that wants to return information from an online database, it's a public application which anyone has free access to. What is a safe approach for these clients to communicate with the database?

I am interested in how this is done in professional environments. When I tried to do research all I could find were examples of clients connecting directly to the database themselves, leaving their connection strings in the code, these examples I'm sure were for server sided/private applications. But in my scenario I assume there has to be a proxy in between.

Do I set up a web server with PHP scripts that returns results or do I program a server that listens for TCP/IP connections? I feel there is a better way but can't lay my finger on it.

What my question boils down to is essentially..

What technique is used for this 'proxy' and client to communicate? What does the setup look like? Even a diagram would be great. Assume I am working in C#.

Comment: Most databases already have desktop applications available if the intent is to have your users write their own sql.  Examples are SSMS for sql server and sql developer for oracle.  All you would have to manage is permissions.

Comment: My apologies if some of my writing is a little unclear. Maybe a more specific example, think of returning high scores from a database in a game. How would the clients return these without connecting directly to the SQL DB?

Comment: WCF sounds like something you may want to take a look at.

Comment: @Lunyx Thank you. Just "WCF" its self was a great pointer into the right direction, I'm reading up on it and trying out examples. This answered a lot of the questions I had.